# Array is being modified

Tags: c

I'm trying to replicate the function strcat. The problem is that my array src is being modified even though I'm just use it to copy.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *ft_strcat(char *dest, char *src)
{
    int i = 0;
    int c = 0;

    while (dest[i] != '\0')
        i++;
    while (src[c] != '\0')
    {
        dest[i] = src[c];
        c++;
        i++;
    }
    dest[i] = '\0';
    return dest;
}


int main(void)
{
    char src[] = "_And Good Bye";
    char dest[] = "Hello World";
    char *ptr;

    printf("\nString 1: %s\nString 2: %s\n", src, dest);

    ptr = ft_strcat(dest, src);
    
    printf("\nAfter strcat function.\nString 1: %s\nString 2: %s\n", src, dest);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
String 1: _And Good Bye
String 2: Hello World

After strcat function.
String 1: And Good Bye
String 2: Hello World_And Good Bye
```

After I run `ft_strcat(dest, src)`, my char `src` looses the character, `"_"`. I don't understand why if I only use it to be copied.

I expect that `src` is not modified.

Comment: `dest` only has enough space to hold the string you initialized it with. When you concatenated to it, you wrote outside the array bounds. That memory happened to overlap with `src`.

Comment: `char dest[1000] = "Hello World";`

Comment: Try to implement `ft_strncat()` instead, then your function will not be a cause of buffer-overflow.

Comment: you can use the "string" and move to "char" board

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dest` has exactly enough memory to store `"Hello World"`. When you append `src` to it you're overwriting adjacent memory. That adjacent memory happens to contain `src`. There's no guarantee that it will, but stack memory is often allocated this way.

For example, if I print out the memory address of `src` and `dest` I see...

```
printf("src: %p\ndest: %p\n", &src, &dest);
```

```
src: 0x7ffeea74e31a
dest: 0x7ffeea74e30e
```

The memory looks like this.

```
001111111111111111
ef0123456789abcdef         
Hello World0_And Good Bye0
^           ^
dest        src
```

When you concatenate src onto dest you overwrite the adjacent memory resulting in...

```
001111111111111111
ef0123456789abcdef         
Hello World_And Good Bye00
^           ^
dest        src
```

You need to allocate `dest` to have enough space.

```
// "Hello World" + "_And Good Bye" + null byte
char dest[25] = "Hello World";
```

In a real program you'd allocate dest as dynamic memory and reallocate it to have enough space.

```
char *dest = malloc(12);
strcpy(dest, "Hello world");
dest = realloc(dest, strlen(dest) + strlen(src) + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The actual type of a string literal in C is `char [N]`, wherein `N` is the minimum amount of space required to store the characters of the string, including the null terminating byte.

In the case where you use a string literal to initialize an array of an unknown size (`char foo[] = ...`), the resulting array is given the same typing as the string literal.

So in,

```
char src[] = "_And Good Bye";
char dest[] = "Hello World";
```

`src` will have the type `char [14]`, and `dest` the type `char [12]`.

Knowing this, it becomes obvious that `dest` does not have enough room to append the contents of `src` (zero excess memory, in fact). Care must always be taken to guarantee that there is enough room, otherwise you risk [Undefined Behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

At a minimum, you would need `char dest[25]`, though it may be prudent to drastically oversize your destination buffer.

```
char dest[512] = "Hello World";
const char *src = "_And Good Bye";
```

Initializing `dest` in this way fills the rest of its memory with zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

For starters the function should be declared at least like

```
char *ft_strcat(char *dest, const char *src);
```

because the source string is not changed within the function.

Within the function you are trying to append the source string to the end of the destination string but the array that contains the destination string has no enough memory to accommodate also the source string, See the declarations of the arrays

```
char src[] = "_And Good Bye";
char dest[] = "Hello World";
```

You need to enlarge the array `dest`.

For example you could write

```
char src[] = "_And Good Bye";
char dest[ 2 * sizeof( src )] = "Hello World";
```

Objects of the type int in general are unable to store all possible lengths of strings. For example the function `strlen` or the operator `sizeof` return values of the type `size_t`

In fact the declarations of the variables `i` and `c`

```
int i = 0;
int c = 0;
```

are redundant within the function.

The function can look the following way

```
char * ft_strcat( char *dest, const char *src )
{
    char *p = dest;

    while ( *p ) ++p;
    while ( ( *p++ = *src++ ) != '\0' );

    return dest;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Try to use Const modifier in source parameter. that's my first point.

char *strcat(char *destination, const char *source)

Comment: This "answer" makes not attempt to answer the actual question. Instead, it only provides (good) off-topic advice to the OP. Therefore, it would be appropriate to post this as a comment, not as an answer. Unfortunately, you do not yet have sufficient reputation to post comments on Stack Overflow. You may want to read this: [Why do we need 50 reputation to make comments?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252133/12149471)